# Find value of a cell according to month and year

Tags: excel, vba, datetime, excel-formula, datetime-format

I’m sorry in advance if I’m not clear for you.

I have for example :

```
Figure 1 :

| A        |       B  |
|01/05/2019|     500  |
|01/07/2020|  -100000 |
|01/12/2020|    7633  |
```

And

```
Figure 2 :

|     A    |   B       |
|01/05/2019|  -0.3521  |
|01/07/2020|    0.455  |
|01/12/2020|       0   |
```

I would like to include in the formulas in column B of Figure 1, the value associated with the month and year in relation to column A in figure 2 (found with the date in column A figure 1), bearing in mind that the days are different.

Thank you.

Comment: Then what would be your desired result? Explain little more to get the result.

Comment: Ty Harun for editing my post. I would like for example B3 figure 1 will be multiplicated by the value B3 figure 2 thanks to column A of figure 1 which will look for same month and year in column A figure 2. Like VLOOKUP but only for month and year I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to use a helper column, containing unique information on the month and the year. Question is, how will you do this? I propose following formula:

```
Helper(date) = 12*Year(date) + Month(date)
```

Where `Year()` and `Month()` are the basic Excel function for retrieving the year number and the month number of the date. Using this approach, you can then use the `VLookup()` function for finding the column you are looking for, something like:

```
Figure1:
========

Helper |          A |       B  |
 24233 | 01/05/2019 |     500  |
 24247 | 01/07/2020 |  -100000 |
 24252 | 01/12/2020 |    7633  |

Figure2: (with some modification, I used the second day of the month to clarify 
========  the correctness of the provided formula)

Helper |          A |       B  |
 24233 | 02/05/2019 |  -0.3521 |
 24247 | 02/07/2020 |    0.455 |
 24252 | 02/12/2020 |       0  |
```

As you can see, a simple `VLookup()` can be used for searching for the values 24233, 24247, 24252, ...

Comment: Shame that I cant upvote otherwise I would have done it. Thank you for this answer yes it’s a possibility but it’s not very ergonomic to create a column for this. However the solution is great.

Comment: @user14124037: you're welcome. In case you don't like to see the added column, you might make it invisible. No problem using `VLookup()` or any other Excel function on invisible cells or columns.

Comment: True. I’ll validate your answer if there are no better proposals. Thank you for your time Dominique.

Comment: @LuckyFr You can vote on answers you accepted, even without reputaion.

Comment: But yours lack expected result,although Dominique assumed your needs ;) btw, comment on question, should be added to question if contains gerneral infos.